# Dynamically change fetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am stuck with an issue: in my project I'm using Core Data to manage data. I've got a single `fetchResultsController` used in all the project.

In **AppDelegate.m** I perform a fetch request and everything is ok. The data is shown in 2 tableViews: **AllRecipes** and **FavouriteRecipes**. I need to somehow get all the recipes in **AllRecipesViewController** and only favourite recipes **FavouriteRecipesViewController**.

I set a predicate to get only favourite recipes in the **FavouriteRecipesViewController** `viewDidAppear` method and a predicate to get all the recipes in **AllRecipesViewController**.
But I'm not sure that this is ok to do.

Can anyone tell me a better way to do it?

Comment: Why only a single FRC? Why not just let each view controller have its own? And what's the purpose of the fetch you're doing in the app delegate?

Comment: I app delegate I load all the recipes which can be accessed through FavouriteRecipesTableViewController and AllRecipesTableViewController. And those recipes can be updated and deleted in another viewController. Besides there is a viewController for adding new recipes. And I use single FRC just to be sure that the information is updated after every change. I was thinking about each viewController having its own FRC but I didn't know how to make tableViews know about all the changes in data. And besides I'm a newbie =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do two things:

1. Have a separate `NSFetchedResultsController` for each view and do the fetching when the new `UIViewController` is instantiated (what I would do).
2. Update the predicate on the `NSFetchedResultsController` and re-fetch each time
   you go to a new `UIViewController` (what I would *not* do).

Comment: I don't really like the second variant which I used in my project but I don't understand how my tableViewControllers will know about the changes in data and rebuild the tables if I use separate FRCs

Comment: If you have separate FRC that are created when a `UIViewController` is instantiated (in `viewDidLoad`)then each time you navigate to that view, it will fetch the latest data. So lets say your in all recipes and add one as your favorite. So you update the `NSManagedObject` and save the context. Now when you navigate to your other `UIViewController` and fetch from the backing store, you'll be fetching the latest information.

Comment: Also note that, in general, you should only have to explicitly fetch through the FRC when you create it, or if you update its fetch request. The whole point of it is to watch Core Data for new/changed/removed objects.

Comment: Sorry, can the second approach affect the application performance badly?

Comment: No necessarily. It really depends on the amount of data your fetching. If your fetching 10^5 records then yes but if it's only a couple hundred it's fine. What good about using option 1 is that you can implement caching for each respective FRC. When you push to a VC you've already been to, when you create the FRC you can fetch from the cache. In option 2 you can't do that.